# A file uploading website allowing all types of files dangerous?

Tags: php, html

When creating an uploading sharing site, is it possible that users may upload their own php scripts and have it run automatically even tho they don't know where the website uploader put that script file? For instance if the website uploads your php file but names it a random name and puts it in a secret directory could this script still contact another server via some PHP OnLoad function? or does the script necessarily need to be executed by someone for it to run its contents?

Comment: You could let them *upload* a nuclear bomb if you wanted to. It's a matter of making sure they aren't able to *execute* things that they shouldn't be able to. Keeping the files out of a web-accessible directory would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP script is not auto-runnable. I mean, It has to be executed by someone or something as a software on your computer needs to be executed by someone or something.

You can protect your upload directory with a htaccess to prevent the access/execution by your browser.

Comment: will this also prevent access for other types of scripts? or is it only for php?

Comment: With a htaccess, you can blocks complete access. You could place php script in a PHP directory and deny the execution.

Comment: That's just wrong, just request it in your browser and it will get executed automatically...

Comment: No problem! as @Jprofitt said, you could upload a nuclear bomb if you want and nobody will be able to execute it (on a secure htaccess!)

Comment: @jeroen With an htaccess he will not be able to execute it.

Comment: That last addition is a good one, but the first part is still very wrong.

Comment: Absolutly not.  A PHP script is not auto-runnable and without access, It's impossible to execute the script.

Comment: "It has to be executed by someone or something as a software on your computer needs to be executed by someone or something". Software as cron and someone to execute a software as a browser. I don't understand to problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the uploads into an unaccessible folder in your website. (You can achieve that with a .htaccess file).

Than you just need a script which handles the downloads. You should now that if some one wants to upload for example an exe file he could also rename it. But it if you want to just protect against attacks where php code is uploaded and accessed this method should work fine.